# Hosting spring mvc 4 (java config) + Hiberante + postgresql + Maven Hosting on some web server

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, hosting, web-hosting

This question has been asked many times before, but the answer is time dependent so i suspect the previous answers could be outdated. I have completed my first web project in Spring mvc 4 + Hibernated + Maven and postgresql. I am not sure how to launch this website(Make it live). There are many options Like on cloud or vps and also Google app(free until certain crowd). Please suggest some good options. And how google app engine works, can i just upload my project on google as it is now(In maven architecture ). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Amazon aws elastic bean stalk is simple and free tier works great when for developing project.